# Xamarin.iOS Label frame in custom TableViewCell is not updated after populating it with data

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to achieve a dynamic height label in tableView cell, but faced a strange problem that I do not know how to solve as it appears on iOS 7.1 and iOS 8.3, but not appears on iOS 8.2, which is very confusing. My current implementation is: 1. Populate custom tableView cell label with data 2. In cell's LayoutSubviews() calculate and set a new frame height for the label so that all text would fit in. When i try to test my implementation, label size is not updating on iOS 7.1 and iOS 8.3, but when i touch the cell it updates directly and is shown as need. However, this is not happening on iOS 8.2 as everything works well. Here's my code for populating custom TableViewCell with data and updating label's frame:

```
partial class DetailsCell : UITableViewCell
{

    public DetailsCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
    }
    public override void LayoutSubviews(){


        base.LayoutSubviews ();
        address.Lines = 0;
        var labelHeight = StringExtensions.StringSize (accountAddress.Text, address.Font).Height;
        address.Frame = new CGRect (address.Frame.X, address.Frame.Y, address.Frame.Width, labelHeight);
        address.SizeToFit ();

    }

    internal void Populate(ListItem item)
    {
        address.Text = item.Details;
        image.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("cell.png");
        SetNeedsLayout();
    }



}
```

StringExtensions.StringSize method calculates height for label according to it's content size and works well as Row height in tableView Datasource is also set to it's value.

Maybe some faced this problem before or know how to solve it? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you implemented `GetHeightForRow` in `UITableViewDataSource`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I heard that this might be bug in Xamarin.